# Convert HWND to IntPtr (CLI)

Tags: c#, mfc, c++-cli, command-line-interface

I have a HWND in my C++ MFC code, and I want to pass this HWND to a C# control and get it as IntPtr.

What Is wrong in my code, and how can I do it correctly?
(I think it's something with wrong using of the CLI pointers, because I get an error that it cannot convert from System::IntPtr^ to System::IntPtr. But I don't know how exactly to make it all to work properly...)

My C++ MFC code:

```
HWND myHandle= this->GetSafeHwnd();
m_CLIDialog->UpdateHandle(myHandle);
```

My C# code:

```
public void UpdateHandle(IntPtr mHandle)
{
   ......
}
```

My CLI code:

```
void CLIDialog::UpdateHandle(HWND hWnd)
{
   System::IntPtr^ managedhWnd = gcnew System::IntPtr();
   HWND phWnd; // object on the native heap

   try
   {

       phWnd = (HWND)managedhWnd->ToPointer();
        *phWnd = *hWnd; //Deep-Copy the Native input object to Managed wrapper.

       m_pManagedData->CSharpControl->UpdateHandle(managedhWnd);
    }
```

Error (cannot convert from IntPtr^ to IntPtr) currently occurs on `m_pManagedData->CSharpControl->UpdateHandle(managedhWnd);`

if I change the CLI code to:

```
void CLIDialog::UpdateHandle(HWND hWnd)
{
   System::IntPtr managedhWnd;
   HWND phWnd; // object on the native heap

   try
   {

       phWnd = (HWND)managedhWnd.ToPointer();
        *phWnd = *hWnd; //Deep-Copy the Native input object to Managed wrapper.

       m_pManagedData->CSharpControl->UpdateHandle(managedhWnd);
    }
```

So in this case the value gotten in C# is 0.

How can I make it work properly?

Comment: can you post minimal code to reproduce the error, as well as telling where the error occurs exactly?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To convert from HWND (which is just a pointer) to IntPtr you have to invoke its constructor, and you do not need gcnew as it's a value type.
So this should work to pass a HWND from native to managed:

```
void CLIDialog::UpdateHandle( HWND hWnd )
{
  IntPtr managedHWND( hwnd );
  m_pManagedData->CSharpControl->UpdateHandle( managedHWND );
}
```

And this is a function you can invoke from managed code and get a native HWND from in native code:

```
void SomeManagedFunction( IntPtr hWnd )
{
  HWND nativeHWND = (HWND) hWnd.ToPointer();
  //...
}
```